# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I installed spark 2.4.3 and sbt 1.2.8. I'm under windows 10 pro.

`java -version` gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

I try to execute the [Quick Start](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) from spark.apache.org

All runs fine until I use sbt. I then get the following exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize

I read a lot about the importance of having the good version of spark with the good version of scala

my build.sbt is:

```
name := "simple-app"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
```

my code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    print("Hello !\r\n")
    val logFile = "D:/bin/spark/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
    val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

if I comment

```
    //val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    //val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    //println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
```

I well read `Hello !` in my console.

I run each line of `main` in `spark-shell` no error at all.

The corresponding python script is successfully submited

What do I miss ?

Comment: @hadooper I have all ready read this, it is close but not excatly. I finally found my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Finally it is effectively a Spark/Scala versions compatibility problem

from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html one can read:

> Note that, Spark is pre-built with Scala **2.11** except version  2.4.2,
>   which is pre-built with Scala 2.12

What I miss read and understand *from 2.4.2 version of spark*. Beside the quick start stands :

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
```

Finally I check the `jars` directory of my spark installation and I found:

```
scala-compiler-2.11.12.jar
scala-library-2.11.12.jar
...
```

So I change my `built.sbt` to:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

and fix the problem (this one at least).